# Changing series color in highcharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been able to change the stroke color on a spline graph, but the points and the legend do not change color until after I hide and show the series by clicking it and then mousing over each of the points.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/J56hm/2/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });

    // the button handler
    $('#button').click(function() {
        chart.series[0].color = "#FF0000";
        chart.series[0].graph.attr({ stroke: '#FF0000' });

        $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
           point.graphic.attr({ fill: '#FF0000' });
         });
        chart.series[0].redraw();
        chart.redraw();
    });
});​
```

Any idea why this is happening or a way to work around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following thread on the highcharts forum has a solution:

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7075&p=33437 with a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G5Pk7/ that illustrates it.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    series.color = "#FF00FF";
    series.graph.attr({ 
        stroke: '#FF00FF'
    });
    chart.legend.colorizeItem(series, series.visible);
    $.each(series.data, function(i, point) {
        point.graphic.attr({
            fill: '#FF00FF'
        });
    });
    series.redraw();
});
```

This is clearly a dirty solution, but seems to work.

Comment: why do you consider this a 'dirty' solution? This worked great for me!

Answer (score 40):

it's simple, you can use this code

```
chart.series[0].options.color = "#008800";
chart.series[0].update(chart.series[0].options);
```

Comment: seems that when the data of the chart is updated the colors are reset back to default ones, any ideas on how to keep the updated colors ?

Answer (score 5):

Did you even look at the console?

> ReferenceError: series is not defined
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net/J56hm/1/show/
>   Line 39

Changing into to following solved the issue

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
...
}
```

But now the opposite happens, when you hover over the points it goes blue again
You are trying to directly manipulate the svg that is rendered by highcharts by setting color attributes. This isn't the correct way, as highchart may redraw the chart based on its rendering algorithm and all your changes may be lost.
After having said all that, I still don't know any supported method in highcharts to do this, will update the answer if I come up with something

[@ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/637ns/)

Comment: My mistake with the error. I was in a rush when I posted the question and didn't look at the console. My question still stands, though I may have found a dirty work around, even if it does involve modifying the underlying SVG.