# Highcharts : Change spline chart color dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts spline chart to plot data dynamically from MySQL DB.

Graph displays response time of websites which considers http status code of websites too.

Whenever http status code are 500, 404, 400 (for example) display graph in red and when http status code changes to anything else (say 200) display in blue.

Graph starts with 10 minutes past data from DB, fetches data every minute through AJAX call and plot dynamically.

```
Graph color changes to red but continues plotting with the same colour even when it gets status code not in http_code_arr[].

<script>

function requestData() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_hourly_data.php',
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: 'site_id=' + site_id,
        success: function(data) 
        {   console.log(data); (Posted below)
            var http_code_arr = [500,404,400];
            for($i=0;$i<data.length;$i++)
            {
                         // Change color of chart to red whenever http_code (data[$i][2]) is mentioned in http_code_arr[]. 
            if(jQuery.inArray(data[$i][2], http_code_arr) > -1)
            {

                chart.series[0].setData(data);
                chart.series[0].color = "#FF0000";
                chart.series[0].graph.attr({ stroke: '#FF0000' });
            }
            else
            {
                chart.series[0].setData(data); 
                chart.series[0].color = "#3BBEE3";
                    chart.series[0].graph.attr({ stroke: '#3BBEE3' });
            }
            }       

        },  
         cache: false       
        });
    }   

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph',
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Monitoring'
         },
         xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
         },
         yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Response time (ms)',
                    margin: 80
                }
         },
         series: [{
            name: 'Time',
            data: [],
         }]
      });
      });
    </script>

Return json value from get_hourly_data.php:

[[1359008687000,0.32605385780334,200],[1359008691000,0.31433510780334,200],[1359008694000,0.30737400054932,200],[1359008707000,0.30876302719116,200]]

consoloe.log(data):

[Array[3] 0: 1359009380000
1: 0.3274929523468
2: 404
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[3]
0: 1359009383000
1: 0.31776595115662
2: 200
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[3]
0: 1359009385000
1: 0.30725002288818
2: 404
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[3]
0: 1359009388000
1: 0.3050639629364
2: 200
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
] 



Could anyone please give me a hand?
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

According to this post you are only missing to call redraw on series. And also it addresses how to change the color of series completely including markers and legend too in addition to line object.
[Changing series color in highcharts dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419758/changing-series-color-in-highcharts-dynamically)

```
var series = chart.series[0];
series.setData(data);

if(jQuery.inArray(data[$i][2], http_code_arr) > -1)
{
series.color = "#FF0000";
series.graph.attr({ stroke: '#FF0000' });
}
else
{
series.color = "#3BBEE3";
series.graph.attr({ stroke: '#3BBEE3' });
}

chart.legend.colorizeItem(series, series.visible);

$.each(series.data, function(i, point) {
    point.graphic.attr({
          fill: '#FF00FF'
    });
});

series.redraw();
```