# Highcharts - different fill colors between x coordinates over hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with a simple area chart that I would like to have two different fill colors for once you hover over it, so that the chart is red on the left side and blue (currrent color) on the right side of the hover point x-value.

http://jsfiddle.net/PSdwb/6/

I see that this is how you pick up on the event and grab the x and y values with a mouseover and mouseout:

```
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        console.log('x: '+ this.x +', y: '+ this.y);
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function() {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't seem to find a way to add a different fill color from the x-value once you hover over the area chart. Threshold and negativeFillColor are a good solution *only* if I'm thinking of doing this effect with the y-values, but is there any way I can make something like negativeFillColor/threshold work for a range of x-values?

Thanks

Comment: So marker (circle) on point, should be colored by ie. blue on the left and red on the right ?

Comment: No, the entire fill color in the area chart should be blue on the left and red on the right... based on the point being hover over.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: http://grab.by/p7qo

Comment: So you need to use two series, which will have different colors. http://jsfiddle.net/PSdwb/7/

Comment: Thanks, I understand that for a static chart. But how can I make those two different shadings only  over a mouseover?

Comment: You can try to catch mouseover like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AY5rV/5/

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian says you have to use 2 series, where the first end the second starts.

Maje the firts serie and where the first color has to end and make the second series with null values until it has to start the new color.

Then in the mouseOver event you can change the color of the charth in the way it says in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419758/changing-series-color-in-highcharts-dynamically):

Like this:

```
   plotOptions: {
        area: {
            lineWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        //change color
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function() {
                    ///change color
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [            
    {
        data: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    },{
        data:[null,null,null,null,6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    }
```

Comment: I got that, but how can I make this happen only over a mouseover? What I'm trying to do is have the chart as it is, but only once you hover over a certain point, then you see those two different shades?