# Changing bar colors on data that is within the same series data

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have a php script that is passing this json data to highcharts

```
{"Month":["July", "August", "September", "October"],"Values":[2341, 1245, 989, 1829]}
```

In Highcharts I'm creating a bar chart. The Month is being inserted into xAxis.categories and the Values are being inserted into series[0].data

The chart renders correctly, however, is it possible to change the color of only a single bar within the chart? For example, if I wanted to make the Month of October red while keeping all the other months the default silver color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing series color in highcharts dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419758/)

Comment: I don't believe its a duplicate. I want to know if its possible to change the color of a single bar of a bar chart when the data of the bar chart is all held under the same series.data. If not, is it possible to break up the json data into different series data?

Comment: Can you share your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always simply set colors for series/chart and then set `colorByPoint` to true, see: http://jsfiddle.net/QgBpk/

The good thing is that you don't need to preprocess your data to add color for a specific point.

Comment: Thanks for this! I really like this solution and it was easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The details for how to do this are clear in the API documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color, you can set the color on an individual data point, see here:

So, from your example this does what you want:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: "bar"
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [ "July", "August", "September", "October"]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [2341, 1245, 989, { color: 'red', y: 1829 } ],
    }]
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/aa83x/)

If you want to change the colour later then the linked answer in the comments shows how -- there is a loop there changing all the points, you can use it to change just one.