# Line chart cannot change color use functions

Tags: highcharts

```
function(chart){

    $('#colorchange').click(function() {
        chart.series[0].color = 'yellow';
        chart.redraw();
          chart.series[0].show();

    });
```

This is what I did but only the title color will change and maker's color will change when mouse hover. Any way to change the line and marker color?

Comment: You need up update the chart after changing series options instead: `chart.series[0].update(chart.series[0].options);` RE : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17057495/1606432

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing series color in highcharts dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419758/changing-series-color-in-highcharts-dynamically)

Comment: thx for your guys help

Answer (score 1):

To change series option dynamically use [Series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) like:

```
chart.series[0].update({color:'yellow'});
```